# Laravel inserting data into two different tables

Tags: laravel, vue.js

Why doesn't my function store inputs into two different tables?

```
public function store(Request $request) {

    $this->validate($request,[
        'product_name' => 'required|string|max:191',
        'quantity' => 'required|integer',
        'product_id' => 'required',
        'category' => 'string|max:191',
        'brand' => 'string|max:191',
        'provider_id' => 'required'
    ]);

    return Product::create([
        'product_name' => $request['product_name'],
        'quantity' => $request['quantity']
    ]); 

    return ProductDetails::create([
        'product_id' => $request['product_id'],
        'category' => $request['category'],
        'brand' => $request['brand'],
        'provider_id' => $request['provider_id']
    ]);    
}
```

The function only executes the `return Product::create`, however if I remove or put `return ProductDetails::create` before `return Product::create`, it does work, but only executes `return ProductDetails::create`.

Comment: you can't have 2 returns in a method - it will only execute and die after the first one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`return` kills the execution of the function and returns the value.

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        //
        $this->validate($request,[
            'product_name' => 'required|string|max:191',
            'quantity' => 'required|integer',
            'product_id' => 'required',
            'category' => 'string|max:191',
            'brand' => 'string|max:191',
            'provider_id' => 'required'
        ]);

        $product = Product::create([
            'product_name' => $request['product_name'],
            'quantity' => $request['quantity']
        ]); 

        $productDetails = ProductDetails::create([
            'product_id' => $request['product_id'],
            'category' => $request['category'],
            'brand' => $request['brand'],
            'provider_id' => $request['provider_id']
        ]);

        return $product;

    }
```